# Apex Trigger: Insert record in custom object

Tags: apex, trigger, related-list

A bit lost on how to finish this trigger.

Scenario: 
 - After creating a new opportunity
 - Object Implementation should populate a list of 12 Records
 - Each record then has it’s own set of task 
 - Task’s may range from 10 to 30 tasks

```
  trigger IMP on Implementation__c (after insert) {  
        List <Implementation__c> ImpToInsert = new List <Implementatiom__c> 
    for (Implementation : Trigger.new) {
```

Am I headed in the right direction? I tried following the example in this link but I got a little lost as my scenario is a little different. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176618&language=en_US [image]

Thanks!

Comment: This is like asking: "I need a trigger to be able to xxx, Here is what I have so far `trigger my trigger on Account(before insert){}` now I am lost, please help....This site deals with specific issues not writing code for you. Where are you stuck. To Directly answer your question yes you are on the right track but there is so much to consider....

Comment: You're going to need to provide more than three lines of code for us to be able to guide you.  You also need to pay more attention to the code you're writing; you've misspelt `Implementation__c` as `Implementatiom__c` and you've got the `new List<Implementation__c>();` syntax wrong.

Comment: A Consideration: How do you know what tasks to create,is it based on implementation type, predefined, Maybe the App Action Plans may help you out and fit into your scenario

Comment: You will also need to pay attention to your requirements which state "After creating a new opportunity", which would suggest your trigger is on opportunity not Implementation

Comment: I do agree with Eric and SB...your requirements are also a little difficult to understand. When you say "Object Implementation should populate a list of 12 Records" what exactly do you mean? It also sounds like you want the trigger on Opportunity (so that it's fired when an Opportunity is created), not on Implementation__c

Comment: Unless the VF page in the question creates the implementation record, then again, just another reason this is Too Broad......

Comment: @SBeauvais34 - The put the trigger on Opportunity. Considerations, should it run for ALL opportunities if not how to you know which ones it should run on, is the above a VF page, if so, no trigger needed, use the class to create the records after you create the opportunity, etc....

Comment: How do the tasks fit in? Are they associated to the Opportunity or? This is why it's important to be clear and detailed in your original post, it's difficult to help when we don't fully understand your needs :)

Comment: I want to eliminate clicking 12 times for the records. I want them to appear after the opportunity is created. I tried opportunity_c and I am getting Error: Compile Error: Invalid SObject type name: opportunity__c at line 1 column 16

Comment: SMH: Nowhere in your code you posted in the text `Opportunity__c` - Look at all these people wanting to help you and you fail to take any direction to be specific. How can we debug code you do not even post??? Mindreader's.. And could it need to be Opportunity and Not Opportunity__c? Only custom objects end with __c

Comment: @Eric I understand everyone is trying to help on this feed. There is no need for your non-positive comments. I never asked PLEASE WRITE THIS CODE for me. I asked the questions in my original post. Please, it is hard enough trying to understand how to write these triggers. You do not have to help if you do not want to. I will figure it out and be more specific with what it is I am trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: What @Eric is saying is that the error you said you're currently getting can only arise from you having "Opportunity__c" in your code, but you didn't include it in the original post. So it's difficult to help you when you're not even posting the code you have.

Comment: I asked a similar question recently, and I think the solution fits your problem. I think any issues that you encounter have been answered in this thread: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80442/error-when-trying-to-use-trigger-to-create-object-when-it-is-of-correct-record-t Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Hi there, I also recently asked a question much like this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83596/apex-after-update-delete-child-then-create-new-child

Answer (score 2):

Along with all the comments on you OP, a basic trigger to create multiple contacts for Account

```
trigger createContacts on Account(After Insert){

Contact[] c = New Contact[]{};

for(Account a : trigger.new){
 for(integer x=0;x<10;x++){
    c.add(New Contact(AccountID = a.id, LastName="LastName ' + x));
 }
}

insert c;

}
```

Per your comment:

1. You forgot the () after instantiating the List
2. _c should be __c
3. DO NOT put Inserts inside a for loop. Populate the list then Insert
4. You have a catch but no try
5. No need to use a try catch for dml (unless use case requires it, use allornone = false and evaluate

   ```
   trigger IMP on Opportunity (after insert) { 
    List <implementation__c> ImpToInsert = new List <implementation__c>(); 

    for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
     implementation__c rec = new implementation__c (Opportunity__c = o.id); 
     ImpToInsert.add(rec);
   }

   database.saveResult[] sr = database.insert(impToInsert,false);  

   for(integer x=0;x<sr.size();x++){
     if(sr[x].isSuccess() == false)
         system.debug(logginglevel.error,sr[x].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'for' at line 3 column 0                           trigger IMP on Opportunity (after insert) {  
    List <implementation_c> ImpToInsert = new List <implementation__c> 
for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {

implementation_c = new implementation_c ();
insert impToInsert;
    } catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
        system.debug (e);
    }
  
}

Comment: @SBeauvais34 - See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting the following error with the updated code. Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'for' at line 4 column 1

Comment: @SBeauvais34 - Sorry I forgot to correct my point #1 in your code

Comment: Once you get it, you should consider compartmentalizing the code into a class and have the trigger simple call the code with the records list. Doing so may allow you to reuse the code in other classes that may need to do the same thing. But that is another topic

Comment: trigger IMP on Opportunity (after insert) { 
     List <implementation__c> ImpToInsert = new List <implementation__c> ();
    
     for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) 
     {
       implementation__c rec = new implementation__c (implementation__c = o.id); 
       ImpToInsert.add(rec);
     }
    
    database.saveResult[] sr = database.insert(impToInsert,false);  
    
     for(integer x=0;x<sr.size();x++)
     {
        if(sr[x].isSuccess() == false)
          system.debug(logginglevel.error,sr[x].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
     }

Comment: This worked but a single record ID pulls over not the 12 records that are listed in the Implementation object.

Comment: @SBeauvais34 - Because you are iterating over a single opportunity. You need to add login for each opportunity to create the 12 records. taking into consideration all comment on your original question

Comment: @SBeauvais34 and login in my comment should be logic dang autocorrect